# "type mismatch" when static array is reused

Tags: arrays, asp-classic

I am modifying an ASP program used to display performance evaluation scores for employees.  The scores range from 0-4 or "N/A" on various topics (e.g., Meets deadlines = 4).  An "N/A" is saved as null in the database.  The topics are grouped into sections (e.g., Fierce Resolve, Reliability, etc.)  The program was lacking an average score for each section. I created an array for the first section which is comprised of six scores. After loading the array, I calculate the average.
This works fine for the first employee row of data.  But when the second employee row is read, I get a "type mismatch" error on the dim averages(5) statement just after that first DEBUG line.  The error does not reference anything.  :-(
Can someone lend me a hand?

```
'   01-26-15 JTF    Determine the average score for Fierce Resolve
    dim totl
    totl = 0
    dim cnt
    cnt = 0
    dim x
    dim sum_1_6
    dim avg_1_6
Response.write("D E B U G:   Create table for ques_1 to 6  <br>")
    dim averages(5)
    averages(0) = ques_1_avg
    averages(1) = ques_2_avg
    averages(2) = ques_3_avg
    averages(3) = ques_4_avg
    averages(4) = ques_5_avg
    averages(5) = ques_6_avg

    for x = 0 to 5
        if  averages(x) <> "" then
Response.write("D E B U G:  loading table: averages(" & x & "):  " & averages(x) & "<br>")
            totl = totl + averages(x)
            cnt  = cnt  + 1
        end if
    next
Response.write("D E B U G:  totl = " & totl & "<br>")
Response.write("D E B U G:  cnt  = " & cnt  & "<br>")
    sum_1_6 = cdbl(totl)
    avg_1_6 = Formatnumber(sum_1_6/cdbl(cnt),2)

    erase averages  ' clear the averages array
```

Comment: Are you sure `averages(5)` is an integer? Maybe check for `if  averages(x) <> "NA"`?

Comment: Is this code within a loop? i.e. Are the dim's being called multiple times? are you using Option Explicit? if so you may need to dim your averages array once at the start of your script and use redim within the loop. (using redim without the preserve keyword will also avoid your use of erase)

Comment: Thanks, Robert - the values are either 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 or null.

Comment: Thanks, HeavenCore - Yes, the code is contained in a loop so the dim *are* being called multiple times.  The code is using Option Explicit. I will try your suggestion of dim'ming at the start, and redim in the loop and will drop use of erase - and report back here soonest.

Comment: HeavenCore - you were right: Moving the "dim averages(5) " outside the loop did the trick!  But I had to drop the use of redim in the loop because "This array is temporarily fixed or locked."  After I removed the redim (and the erase), all is Golden.  Mahalo plenty, brah!